# I'm getting a bug (an infinite loop) when I try to update my context

Tags: react-context, next.js13

I am encountering an infinite loop when trying to update my context in Next.js 13.4.5. Despite trying everything, I am unable to locate the error. However, all components can read the context without any issue.

This is the context:

'use client'

import { createContext, useState } from 'react'

export const FiltersContext = createContext()

export function FiltersProvider ({ children }) {
const [filters, setFilters] = useState({
brand: 'all',
minPrice: 110
})

return (
<FiltersContext.Provider value={{
filters,
setFilters
}}>
{children}
</FiltersContext.Provider>
)
}

```
This is the layout:


import "../styles/globals.css"
import { Header } from "@/components/header/Header"
import { Inter } from "next/font/google"
import { FiltersProvider } from "@/contexts/filtersContext"

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] })

export const metadata = {
   title: "WebSite",
   description: "Generated by create next app",
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
   return (
      <html lang="en">
         <body className={inter.className}>
            <FiltersProvider>
               <Header />
               {children}
            </FiltersProvider>
         </body>
      </html>
   )
}
```

Please refer to the images for the page where I want to display the products, the filters component, and my custom hook, respectively:

[Page where I want to show the products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E5c6.png)

[Filters component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrZnP.png)

[My custom hook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8hhN.png)